# storing the retrieved datas to the database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a php form with three text boxes (webmeasurementsuiteId, webmeasurementsId, Id) and the values in the text boxes are retrieved from other tables of the database. Now my task is to submit the retrieved values in this php form named (mapping) to the database. I have created the table with the following syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE `mapping` (
  `webmeasurementsuiteId` INT NOT NULL,
  `webmeasurementsId` INT NOT NULL,
  `Id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (Id)
);
```

But I am getting an sql error as follows:

```
INSERT INTO mapping(webmeasurementsuiteId,webmeasurementsId,Id) values ('','','7')

ERROR: Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'webmeasurementsuiteId' at row 1
```

Can anyone correct my error?

Comment: please see my coding at this link http://pastebin.com/vn4rzgC3.I cannot correct the "insert into" statement since it is the error displayed.I have already got the values in the text boxex which are retrieved from other tables.as such i am not entering anything except the id field and I want these values to be stored in the database.

Comment: oh sorry!!check this link http://pastebin.com/ZHiCVbzv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all your columns are `INT` that means numbers while your insert statement is inserting `STRING`s (text) remove the `'` around the values in the `INSERT`-statement and it should work

example:

```
INSERT INTO mapping(webmeasurementsuiteId,webmeasurementsId,Id) values (0,0,7)
```

Comment: please see my coding at this link http://pastebin.com/vn4rzgC3.I cannot correct the "insert into" statement since it is the error displayed.I have already got the values in the text boxex which are retrieved from other tables.as such i am not entering anything except the id field

Comment: please see my coding at this link http://pastebin.com/vn4rzgC3.I cannot correct the "insert into" statement since it is the error displayed.I have already got the values in the text boxex which are retrieved from other tables.as such i am not entering anything except the id field and I want these values to be store in the database.

Comment: webmeasurementsuitesid:
1
webmeasurementsId:
75674594     
75674605
75674606
75674607
75674608  Id:7

.These are the datas in my php page at present which i want to enter into the database.

Answer (score 0):

So you used '' for webmeasurementsuiteId which indicates it as a string. just leave the integers to 0 without the parantheses to indicate them as an integer. `values (0,0,7)` should probably do it.

Comment: please see my coding at this link http://pastebin.com/vn4rzgC3.I cannot correct the "insert into" statement since it is the error displayed.I have already got the values in the text boxex which are retrieved from other tables.as such i am not entering anything except the id field and I want these values to be stored in the database.

Comment: It says "Unknown paste id" if i click the link.

Comment: webmeasurementsuitesid:
1
webmeasurementsId:
75674594     
75674605
75674606
75674607
75674608  Id:7

.These are the datas in my php page at present which i want to enter into the database.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot insert blank in the values field . 
try  0 instead of ''
`INSERT INTO mapping(webmeasurementsuiteId,webmeasurementsId,Id) values (0,0,'7')` 
or alter the columns to take the null values

Comment: have a look at the create statement... your example wont work

Comment: please see my coding at this link http://pastebin.com/vn4rzgC3.I cannot correct the "insert into" statement since it is the error displayed.I have already got the values in the text boxex which are retrieved from other tables.as such i am not entering anything except the id field and I want these values to be stored in the database.

Comment: webmeasurementsuitesid:
1
webmeasurementsId:
75674594     
75674605
75674606
75674607
75674608  Id:7

.These are the datas in my php page at present which i want to enter into the database.